# Mouse keeps clicking automatically - 10 clicks per second

Tags: x11, mouse

I'm having an issue with X11 on Debian: the mouse will sometimes start randomly clicking like 10 times per second for about 2 - 3 minutes.

It starts when there's some kind of video content started on the screen, like a YouTube video or a Zoom call. It happens about 20% of the time when this content is started. Once it starts, it won't stop for another 2 - 3 minutes.

It might be my mouse, but I've tried 2 and it happens with both. When I unplug the mouse, it just continues to click.

Anyone know why this might be happening?

[Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/fh7o78m5ivbwqyw/debian-mouse-auto-click.mp4?dl=0) is a video of such an event.

I have a Dell XPS 15 laptop. I've tried disabling all the touchscreen input devices (Wacom) and KVM drivers.

Comment: May be a internal hardware issue. Does it happen in other distros/OS ?

Comment: You might want to debug which device file is sending those "commands" which cause the clicking

Comment: @IbnFulan I was once running Arch Linux (with Xfce) and it never happened. Right now I'm running Debian with Gnome.

Comment: @SirMuffington Okay I'll try that.

Comment: If you think it's an USB device you need to mount `usbmon` and then run WireShark with root rights. In your case I would sniff usbmon0, which has all the USB traffic

Comment: @SirMuffington I have a script ready to run so that when it happens again, I can log X11 inputs. I'll let you know once I find what input device is causing this issue.

Comment: As for logging events: Log not only on the X11 level, also log on the kernel input layer level. `evtest` on `/dev/input/eventX` can show you events coming from those devices.

Comment: @dirkt Added that to my script. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was my Dell touchpad. Device: "DLL080D:01 06CB:7A13 Touchpad".

As my mouse was doing the auto click, I disabled it with `xinput disable 'DLL080D:01 06CB:7A13 Touchpad'` and the clicking stopped instantly.

Thanks to the commenters for helping me out!